# How can I access the RethinkDB context set up by the Hapi plugin?

Tags: rethinkdb, hapi.js

According to this Hapi JS plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/ghostbar/hapi-rethinkdb), The RethinkDB library and the connection are bound to the server context inside handlers on  `this.rethinkdb` and `this.rethinkdbConn`.

However, I'm not being able to access those, only using `request.server.plugins` etc. Does anyone know why? Is it because the context set inside a plugin with `server.bind()` is only available inside the plugin itself ? Thanks!

EDIT: 
Here's is some of the code on index.js

```
const plugins = [{register: require('hapi-rethinkdb'), options: {url: //url here}]

server.register(plugins, () => {
    server.route(require('./routes'))
    server.start()
})
```

The on routes.js, let's say a have a route like this:

```
 {
   method: 'GET',
   path: '/list-of-things',
   handler: function(request, reply) {

      // I have to use it like this:
      const r = request.server.plugins['hapi-rethinkdb'].rethinkdb;
      const connection = request.server.plugins['hapi-rethinkdb'].connection;

      // Because this throws undefined:
      const r = this.rethinkdb;
      const connection = this.rethinkdbConn
   }

 }
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: I've edited the question to show some code. Thanks!

Comment: File a bug on github as the modules tests are not checking if bind is working.  I recommend that module uses server.decorate or server.app instead of expose or binding to hook into hapi's internals.  See my module [here](https://github.com/simon-p-r/hapi-level-mongo/blob/master/lib/index.js#L29) for an example of what I mean

Comment: Thanks Simon. I'll file it on github.